# Building a Solr index and hot swapping it in Prod?

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud

We are planning to setup a Solr cluster which will have around 30 machines. We have a zookeeper ensemble of 3 nodes which will be managing Solr.
We will have new production data every few days, which is going to be quite different from the one that is in Prod. Since the data difference is
quite large, we are planning to use hadoop to create the entire Solr index dump and copy these binaries to each machine and maybe do some kinda core swap.

I am still new to Solr and was wondering if this is a good idea. I could http post my data to the prod cluster, but each update could span multiple documents. 
I am not sure how this will impact the read traffic while the write happens.

Any pointers ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i completely understand your explanations, but it seems to me that you would like to migrate to a new solr cloud environment with zero down time. 
First, you need to know how many shards you want, how many replicas, etc. 
You need to deploy the solr nodes, then you need to use the collection admin API to create the collection as desired (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API). 
After all this you should be ready to add content to your new solr environment. 
You can use Hadoop to populate the new solr cloud, say for instance by using solrj. Or you can use the data import handler to migrate data from another solr (or a relational database, etc).

It is very important how you create your solr cloud in terms of document routing, because it controls in which shard your document will be stored. 
This is why it is not a good idea to copy raw index data to a solr node, as you may mess up the routing. 
I found these explanations very useful about routing: https://lucidworks.com/blog/solr-cloud-document-routing/